# Short story with mechanical house that completes all tasks

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am 90% sure that this by either Isaac Asimov or Ray Bradbury. I think I might have read this in *The Martian Chronicles*. Basically, the story starts off with a house that cooks, cleans, and performs every other menial task required. Something happens that causes a fire to break out but the house doesn't have enough water so it burns down all except for one section. This section contains the spirits (maybe shadows or souls) of the family that lived there.

I read this in around 2000, maybe? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Was the story you're thinking of *"There Will Come Soft Rains"*?

Comment: @Valorum Yes. Quote from the question: "What it isn't: with Google I stumbled upon There Will Come Soft Rains by Ray Bradbury, and the plot is very similar, and the beginning made me think "Bingo!", but I do not remember there being a fire in the story I read, and I also remember a view from a briefly opened door, or window, of a snowy setting, so while it may be that I am confusing elements of another story, or my imagination, with There Will Come Soft Rains, I would still like to run this through here as a question, because I'm not convinced."  I'm not sure what the accepted was then.

Comment: @InventPalooza so is "There Will Come Soft Rains" correct?

Comment: @Stormblessed Yes, it is...